# Retrieving linked user profile property in MVC 5 Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC 5 with Identity V2 and am unable to get a linked property when searching for a user.

My identity user model is this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public School School { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

When i try the following:

```
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then currentUser is correctly populated and I have my value for FullName, however the value for School is null.

The database table for AspNetUsers includes a field called School_SchoolID which contains a value which references the correct record in the School table.

How can I retrieve the details of the linked School property?

Comment: you didn't show the code for FindById() , isn't that the function that is not working properly by not returning a full ApplicationUser object ??

Comment: FindByID is built into the Identity Framework, it's not a function I've written

Comment: Check the database for correct relationship between ApplicationUser table and the School , if not, you have to correctly bind the models when using EF code first.

Comment: DSR is correct, the problem is probably with how you setup the code first relationship between the ApplicationUser and School tables.  Show the code for both entities and how you setup the relationship between them. You say that the AspNetUsers table include a field School_SchoolID but I do not see it defined in ApplicationUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The School property should be virtual if you want the School information to be loaded along with the user profile

```
public virtual School School { get; set; }
```